# IPv6 broken and cannot even ping the own address

Tags: ipv6

I have broken IPv6 in some LXC containers, where the strange thing is, that i cannot even ping the address on the interface.

```
$ ip -6 r
prefix::/112 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
$ ip -6 a show dev eth0
69: eth0@if70: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
inet6 prefix::3/112 scope global tentative dadfailed 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now a `ping6 prefix::3` fails with

```
64 bytes from localhost (::1): Destination unreachable: Address unreachable
```

I tried disabling the firewall (which shouldn't have any effect, as the local packets should not hit the INPUT chain), but this didn't change anything.

Another thing which is strange: The interface did not get a link-local address.

The OS is a rather minimal installation of debian jessie. Other containers with debian jessie installations work fine with IPv6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the output you posted, you will notice `tentative dadfailed`.

This means that the IPv6 duplicate address detection has kicked in for this IP address. Are you absolutely sure that the IP is not in use anywhere else on the same network segment?

You can run `lxc-ls -f` on your LXC hostnodes to figure out if some other container might be using that IP.

Comment: Yes, there actually were ip conflicts. And ``lxc-ls`` is a nice overview.

Comment: @allo With IPv6 you should really avoid manual addressing if you possibly can.

Comment: Yeah i know i know ... but in my setup its the easier way. The alternative would be static VM-MAC-addresses in the LXC config, making the addresses harder to remember, while there is still the need to watch out that a copied VM uses a new address. And i currently only have a single /64 for the physical host.